How/Why is pair annihilation accounted/permitted in QED?
Following Schwartz Intro to QFT, I understand that through the introduction of virtual off-shell particles, we can allow fermion anti-fermion annihilation vertices to exist in QED, as long as the created photon is not a final state, but rather a virtual photon. I also understand that these virtual particles are just a mathematical representation of all the possible time orderings that can happen for a process.
Schwartz provides the example of a $e^+ e^- \rightarrow e^+ e^-$ QED scattering, where the different possible time orderings are calculated using Old Fashioned Perturbation Theory (OFPT), where 3-momentum is strictly conserved at the vertices, but energy is not. This violation of energy conservation is only allowed for intermediate particles through the uncertainty principle. Furthermore, in the OFPT calculations all particles are on shell. It is then finally shown how these contributions give the same result as using the virtual particle diagram. So far, so good.
Now, the problem is that when I try to use this OFPT approach to understand why pair-annihilation into a single intermediate photon would be permitted I can not find a reason why it should be allowed to happen.
To be more clear, even in the OFPT framework, where the intermediate photon can temporarily violate energy conservation, but where all states must be on-shell, if I work in the COM frame, the intermediate photon must have zero momentum, which is not possible. Furthermore, for a 'direct' annihilation we don't have any other type of order, it is just the incoming $e^+$ and $e^-$ meeting at a vertex and creating a $\gamma$, which can then pair-create $\mu^+ \mu^-$, for example. I do not care much about the final states, I am just interested in why the 3-pt annihilation vertex is allowed to happen in QED, when the photon is an intermediate state.
So, the question here would be, how can we argue, without resorting to off-shell particles (which seem more like a mathematical tool than a real physical object), that pair-annihilation should be permitted in QED?
Bonus question: If a virtual particle, by definition does not obey the e.o.m, then why do they propagate? How can they propagate? Or is this just a visual representation, and in reality they are point-like interactions?

There are no lack of textbooks and pages on this site that point out the fact that virtual particles, the whole Feynman diagram she-bang, are all fictitious computational artefacts. Reality does not behave that way, but these fictitious computational pebbles are great to arrive at approximate solutions that compare well with experimental outcomes. If we really fully understand how to do perturbations in QFT, we would not have chosen to present things this way, but we don't, and so we have no choice.

I don't know what you mean by "I don't care much about the final state". The final state is the only thing we can measure in an experiment.

@naturallyInconsistent yes, as I said, I understand that virtual particles are more of a mathematical tool to make perturbative calculations more efficient, as are Feynman diagrams. However, even if you don't use the diagrams and do the full calculation of the time ordered matrix elements you would get that the two initial fermion-antifermion states get annihilated at the point where a photon is created. The question is about why this vertex is allowed in QED, without using a virtual photon. Momentum conservation should prohibit it, however it is a very common vertex, why is it allowed?

@FlatterMann the reason I said I don't care about final states is because I am asking about why the 3pt annihilation vertex is allowed in QED without using virtual particles. I understand the photon should be an intermediate state, so I know it must pair create leptons at the end (Assuming initial pair were also leptons). I am not interested in the result of the measurement, magnitude of the contribution, etc. I am interested in why it is physically allowed to have such a vertex, when momentum conservation usually prohibits it for on-shell photons.

First off, the interaction term is $A\bar\psi\psi$, which is the "pair production/annihilation and photon creation/annihilation". But I think your question is deeper, and to that, I can only say that you vastly underestimate how little we know of QFT. Part of the annoyance may be coming from the fact that, actually, all the wavefunctions are wrong, even your definite momentum eigenstates are energetically wrong (or else you wont need to renormalise the mass), and so what looks like Lorentz violations may well just be an artefact. Not having point localisation easily leads to such.

@rafael I am not sure I understand the question "Why is an unphysical state physically allowed?". I can't tell you the precise mathematical reason for the occurrence of terms in these perturbation calculations, but I would not expect them to contain only contributions that can be final states (which are physical). That is already not the case in time-independent perturbation theory of the Schroedinger equation, if I remember correctly. The individual terms of the series do not represent physical states of the unperturbed system. Worse... the series does not even have to converge.

afaik, the reason these fundamental processes have names, Bhabha scattering, Møller scattering, was that they were hard calculations in OFTP, and then Feynman et al. come along with QED (that name itself implies you're fully relativistic, btw) and just do $s \rightarrow t, t \rightarrow s$, or $u$ in Møller scattering, and the tree-level amplitudes fit on a single page was a whole thing. Anyway: look at Bhabha's original paper, maybe?

also: diagrams are in momentum space, in spite of time direction separating the final and initial states, so is there really a problem with a $\vec p =0$ photon if you can violate energy $E=2m_ec^2$ at the vertex? I think the thing with $s$-channel OFTP is that you have auto include a $\gamma e^+e^-$ creation vertex, and then the time-ordered photon goes on the zap the initial state pair out of existence. Maybe. It's been a long time since my last QFT class.

Thank you all for your help. Then, without using virtual particles, and using the OFPT approach, this vertex would imply that an annihilation gives rise to a massive, static $\vec{p}=0$ photon. However, since this state still obeys the e.o.m for the photon field, there isn't any reason why it shouldn't be allowed to exist. The problem was trying to identify this as a physically observable photon, which it is not. Rather, it might be better to think about it as an anomalous excitation of the field that happens in these cases.
